# close an object tag in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading another html page in an  tag and it is getting loaded in an overlay

```
<div id="overlay-inAbox4" class="overlay">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <object id="sendMessageOverlay" data="http://localhost:8000/messages/write/?recipients={{ context_user.username }}" style="height:25rem; width:50rem;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

After doing an operation in the overlay i want to close it.

How can i do this?

I tried doing this by changing the css of $('.overlay') to display:none, but it wont work because $('.overlay') is not accessible within the object tag contents.

Comment: Why are you using an object to fake an `<iframe>`? You end up with pretty much the same result, but without such well documented JS APIs.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid too. The end tag for `<object>` is mandatory.

Comment: You should be able to use `postMessage` to communicate between different pages. The subpage can't affect the parent, but it can tell the parent to affect itself.